# Google Apps Script - removeEditor/Viewer of single user from all files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to remove a single user's editor/viewer access for all files in my Google Drive.  When I tried this, I get the error "No such user".  When I logged getEditor, the only results were "[DriveUser]".  Greatly appreciate any thoughts on how to solve this.  Thank you.

```
function RemoveEditors(){ 

  const EDITOR = "mickey@mouse.com";

  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.removeEditor(EDITOR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is simply modified.

```js
function RemoveEditors() {
  const EDITOR = "mickey@mouse.com";
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var editor = file.getEditors().find(e => e.getEmail() == EDITOR);
    if (editor) {
      file.removeEditor(EDITOR);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

I thought that in the above modification, all files are required to be retrieved. In that case, the process cost might be high. So, in order to reduce the process cost of the script, in this pattern, the files with the editor of `EDITOR` are searched using the search query. And, the editor is removed.

```js
function RemoveEditors() {
  const EDITOR = "mickey@mouse.com";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false`);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.removeEditor(EDITOR);
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, Drive API is used. By this, I thought that when the number of files is large, the process cost might be reduced a little. When you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And also, please install a Google Apps Script library of [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest). [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install)

```js
function RemoveEditors() {
  const EDITOR = "mickey@mouse.com";

  const q = `'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false`;
  let requests = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const obj = Drive.Files.list({ q, fields: "nextPageToken,items(permissions(emailAddress,id,role),id)", maxResults: 1000, pageToken });
    if (obj.items.length > 0) {
      requests = [...requests, ...obj.items.flatMap(({ permissions, id }) => {
        const user = permissions.find(({ emailAddress, role }) => role == "writer" && emailAddress == EDITOR);
        if (user) {
          return {
            method: "DELETE",
            endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${id}/permissions/${user.id}`,
          };
        }
        return [];
      })];
    }
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  if (requests.length == 0) return;
  var result = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests });
}
```

#### References:

- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms)
- [searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams)

### Added:

For example, when the above pattern 2 is used and an error at `file.removeEditor(EDITOR)` is avoided, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample 1:

```
function RemoveEditors() {
  const EDITOR = "mickey@mouse.com";
  var yourEmail = "###your email address###"; // Please set your email address.

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false and '${yourEmail}' in owners`);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.removeEditor(EDITOR);
  }
}
```

- From your reply, I'm worried that you might have no permission for removing the editors of the file. So, in this modification, the files, that you are the owner, are used.

#### Sample 2:

```
function RemoveEditors() {
  const EDITOR = "mickey@mouse.com";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false`);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    try {
      file.removeEditor(EDITOR);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(`Error message: ${e.message}, Error file: ${file.getId()}`);
    }
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when an error occurs at `file.removeEditor(EDITOR)`, the error is skipped by try-catch. And, about the file that an error occurs, the error message and the file ID are shown in the log. By this, I thought that the reason for the issue might be found.

Comment: I tried Pattern 2 and it worked.  Thank you so much!  I am so grateful for your helpful response.

Comment: Not sure why but, Pattern 2 is now throwing "Exception: Access denied: DriveApp." at the line "file.removeEditor(EDITOR);"  Might anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: @Tak Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `I tried Pattern 2 and it worked. Thank you so much! I am so grateful for your helpful response.` and `Not sure why but, Pattern 2 is now throwing "Exception: Access denied: DriveApp." at the line "file.removeEditor(EDITOR);" Might anyone have any thoughts?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your situation?

Comment: @Tak Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your reply, for example, when you want to use my pattern 2 and you want to avoid `"Exception: Access denied: DriveApp."`, when you modify ``var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false`);`` to ``var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`'${EDITOR}' in writers and trashed=false and '${yourEmail}' in owners`);``, what result will you obtain? Because I'm worried that you might have no permission of the file. If this was not useful, how about using try-catch like `try { file.removeEditor(EDITOR); } catch(_) {}`?

Comment: In above case, please declare `var yourEmail = "###your email address###";`.

Comment: @Tak About your current issue, in order to avoid this, I added 2 more samples by reflecting on my previous comments. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tried the modified Sample 2 and it seemed to work.

Comment: @Tak Thank you for replying and testing it, again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.